# flutter textformfield issue

Tags: flutter

```
  if (isPraticeChecked)
                TextFormField(
                    decoration:
                        const InputDecoration(labelText: 'No.of Questions'),
                    controller: noOfquestionController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ],
                    validator: (value) {
                      final isNum = num.tryParse(value!);
                      
                      if (isNum == null ||
                          int.parse(value) < 1 ||
                          int.parse(value) > 30) {
                        return 'No. of question must be 1 to 30.';
                      }
                      return null;
```

this is the textformfield  keyboardtype.number  this kb only receiving num if user enter other then num like "-",",",".," it is giving blank page

Comment: Could you please share what do you want to achieve and what are you getting right now?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are giving input from your laptop's or pc's keyboard. Don't do this and try it with emulator or your phone. When we choose input type as number, it only shows us a keyboard with numbers only in phone.